Understand this trunk of pine-script tradingview
I have some small code but I can't understand, please explain it, thanks:
atr = mult * ta.atr(length) // series float ?
// longStop is a value of float or series float?
longStop = (useClose ? ta.highest(close, length) : ta.highest(length)) - atr
longStopPrev = nz(longStop[1], longStop) // completely don't understand: return of longStop is series??
longStop := close[1] > longStopPrev ? math.max(longStop, longStopPrev) : longStop


All those variables will be series type.
The reason is explained in the user manual:

Built-in variables such as open, high, low, close, volume, time, and
bar_index, and the result from any expression using such built-ins,
are qualified as “series”. The result of any function or operation
that returns a dynamic value will always be a “series”, as will the
results from using the history-referencing operator [] to access
historical values. Wherever a script allows “series” values, it will
also accept values with any other qualifier, as “series” is the
highest qualifier on the hierarchy.


but look at "nz(longStop[1],..." will return single value when it not null, but when it's null, will return series !?
